# python selenium как скрыть консоль geckodriver.exe

Tags: python, selenium, cx-freeze, gecko

Собственно есть python 3.10, есть приложение на wxPython, далее в нём есть скрипт на Selenium.
Запускаю из PyCharm всё хорошо.
Далее всё приложение собирается в exe с помощью cxFreeze и дальше при запуске приложения когда Selenium за пускает браузер FireFox я вместе с браузером наблюдаю консоль geckodriver.exe до момента закрытия браузера.

Вот часть кода с запуском:

```
profile = Options()
profile.add_argument('-width=1280')
profile.add_argument('-height=720')

profiles = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=profile, firefox_profile=profiles,
                                    executable_path=os.path.abspath(os.curdir) + r'\data\geckodriver.exe')
```

Вопрос как мне его скрыть?
p.s. ещё раз повторюсь при запуске из PyCharm этой консоли нету

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Последние ответы может помогут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983860/hide-chromedriver-console-in-python/71093078#71093078

Comment: спасибо, Сергей!

Comment: еще вариант: запускаете веб-драйвер предварительно в команднике, для работы в режиме remotewebdriver, затем работает ваша программа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение, то что кидали в коменты к сожалению не помогло, нашёл такое

```
import subprocess
import functools
from selenium import webdriver

webdriver.common.service.subprocess.Popen = functools.partial(subprocess.Popen, creationflags=0x08000000)
```